# How to use data attribute value as an ID selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use an ID as a selector by using a data attribute but I can't get it work.

Basically, I have a group of links at the very top. Each link have a unique id. I use these links to create a link on the fly. The link created on the fly has a data attribute set with the id of the one I previously clicked on. Now, I need to target this link with the data attribute using the Id of the link I clicked at first and show the inner text.

How can I set a data attribute (of an element created on the fly) as an ID selector?

Here is the following Javascript code.

```
$('.group-1 a').on('click', function(){

  var block = 
 '<div class="group-2">' +
     '<a href="#" class="child-item" data-item="'+ $(this).attr('id') +'" >Child Item 100</a>' +
  '</div>'; 


$(block).appendTo( $('.host'));


});

$('body').on('click', '.child-item', function(){

      var getId = $(this).attr('data-item');

      var getInner = $('[id="#' + getid + '"]').text();

      $('.result').text(getInner);

})
```

The HTML code:

```
 <div class="group-1">
   <a href="#" id="item-1">Parent Item 100</a>
   <a href="#" id="item-2">Parent Item 200</a>
   <a href="#" id="item-3">Parent Item 300</a>
 </div>

 <hr>

 <div class="host"></div>

 <div class="result"></div>
```

I've prepared a live view at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywfu4tqx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you want is not `'[id="#myId"]'`, but `'[id="myId"]'` (there is no `#`):

```
$('[id="' + getId + '"]')
```

or, since you don't use special chars like `:`:

```
$('#' + getId)
```

[**Fixed** JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ywfu4tqx/1/) (notice you also had `getid` which I changed to `getId`).

Now, it pays to notice in these two cases there are two different selectors: the second is an [ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), and the first is an [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (that happens to be comparing the `id` attribute).

### Important Differences Between the [ID](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [Attribute-Equals](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selectors:

#### 1) Elements with duplicated IDs

When there are **elements with duplicated IDs** (which is invalid HTML, but still can exist): the `#foo` selector **only** fetches the **first** matched element in the DOM (with the `foo` id); and the `[id='foo']` selector fetches all of them.

#### 2) Escaping

In the ID selector, the id is a CSS identifier, so it must match the CSS escaping rules.
In the attribute selector, the attribute value is a string.

For example, say your ID has a `":"` in it:

```
$("#foo:bar"); // INVALID! :bar is intepreted as a (invalid) pseudo-class

$("#foo\\:bar"); // Valid! The : is properly escaped
$("[id='foo:bar']"); // Valid! The : is inside a string
```

Comment: Great Answer! And I learned about ID selectors aswell. Thanks acdcjunior!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be of help! ^^